# What's the pg equivalent of mysql_connect + mysql_select_db combo?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I hope this question isn't too simple, I tried to go through the postgresql and mysql php pages, but I didn't understand quite that well.

If you use PHP with MySQL, you can do something like this:

```
$_connectionID = @mysql_connect(
        $dbConnectionConfig['host'],
        $dbConnectionConfig['user'],
        $dbConnectionConfig['pass'],
        true
    );
@mysql_select_db($dbName, $_connectionID);
```

Uhmm, two quick questions:

1. What's the point of doing the above? Why not just do everything at once with `mysql_pconnect`?
2. What does the `true` in `mysql_connect` do? Does it just allow you to have multiple database connections open at the same time?

Now, how would you go and do this in PostgreSQL? I know about `pg_connect`, but that requires a db name to be specified, so, it's more of an equivalent to `mysql_pconnect`. Also,  I know that the `@` in the mysql php syntax basically hides the errors in case of failure. Does the `@` work for postgres as well?

Thanks for your time, have a good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No reason not to
2. You do not need the `true`

   - The `true` is only needed if it is a new connection link and you have already made a link before.
3. Remove the `@` symbols because they block any PHP warnings that may come up

Comment: So, there isn't a way for Postgres PHP to connect to the server and then connect to a DB? 
Also, is passing `PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW` to `pg_connect` the same as passing `True` to `mysql_connect`?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: In PostgreSQL you *always* connect to a database, never to a db cluster. There is the default maintenance db "postgres" if you don't know which database to connect to.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I see, thanks, that makes sense. 
Uhh, this is getting slightly irrelevant, but I'd rather not make a new question. I know the equivalent of `mysql_real_escape_string` is `pg_escape_string` and `pg_escape_bytea`, but how do you deal with a query that inserts data into both regular columns and bytea columns? Do you pass the query to `pg_escape_bytea` and then to `pg_escape_string`?

Comment: Why not make it a new question? You can ask as many questions as you want as long as they are well researched and formulated and have not been asked before. I am no PHP expert.